# not getting first form in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have this type of each loop with form

```
<% @catagories.each do |cat| %>
    <label>
        Name:
        <%= cat.name %>
    </label>
    <label>
      Public
      <%= form_for cat, :html => {:class => 'visible_in_activity_record'} do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :visible_in_activity_record ,:'data-role'=>"none"%>
      <% end %>
    </label>
<% end %>
```

When i show this results in browser.

First element of loop is without form and after that all element have form.

After that I tried to add code and check form from inspect element in browser but in browser that is getting same issue that i can not see  form in first element of loop.

if anyone faced this type of issue then please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try without the class to be sure it is not hidden by css.

Comment: check `@catagories.first` - what does it return. Ideally this should not be the case unless the first element is nil

Comment: dkp: if @catagories.first is nil, an exception will be raised instead!

Comment: Is there more to this view? Like another form tag surrounding this lot, which should really be a bunch of `fields_for` tags?

Comment: @Syl dkp i am not geting nil record

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `build` or `new` in your controller for categories so the first, or the last will be nil.

You can get around this by checking for a new record before you render the form, like so:

```
<% @catagories.each do |cat| %>
  <%- unless cat.new_record? %>
    <label>
      Name:
      <%= cat.name %>
    </label>
    <div class='label-style'>
      Public
      <%= form_for cat, :html => {:class => 'visible_in_activity_record'} do |f| %>
        <%= f.check_box :visible_in_activity_record ,:'data-role'=>"none"%>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Additionally, if you're interested, it's invalid html to put a whole form inside a `label` field, might be better to create a div that has the same style and behavior has the label.

Comment: no iam not getting nil record i am getting its value when i trash code.
also i tried your solution but still getting same error. thankyou for the answer :)